# PgfPlots:Improving Dashed Lines

Tags: pgfplots

Edit 3: Now I understand that the real issue is tikz externalize. However, I couldn't produce a MWE. My code is long, somehow when I make it shorter, it doesn't compile (however it compiles once I remove tikz externalize). I will wait a few days, maybe someone has experienced a similar problem. If there is no answer, I will accept AboAmmar's solution.

Edit 2: The solution proposed by AboAmmar is enough for my purposes, however I would like to learn solution to problem I described below. I repeat, the code I write below works also for me for a small table. It becomes problematic for large tables. I am not hiding any code.

Edit: I have 30 different tables with thousands of entries. I have already extracted the code. It works when data is small, however when data is large the problem I described arises. I may add a picture when I go home.

My question is very simple, when plot a line with following code, all points are connected with a continuous line. How can I make that line disappear ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot[smooth,red,dashed,line width = 1.5] table {};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please complete your example so that it will compile.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the class just because `minimal` shouldn't be used for examples: `article` or `standalone` are good choices.

Comment: Unfortunately, that code will not compile because it can't do anything with the table in file `.tex` which is what it wants to load :(.

Comment: What you mean width " line disappear". If you like to have only marks, than add option `only marks`  to addplot; `\addplot[red,only marks] table {};`

Comment: @Zarko Is it that simple ? I will try immediately.

Comment: A get a dashed line with your code. (Well, when I add something to it from the manual.)

Comment: @cfr what I get is a dashed line on top of continuous line.

Comment: This is why ***you should post a Minimum Working Example (MWE)*** which we can use to reproduce the problem. How can I know why your code does something different from mine if I don't know how your code differs from mine?

Comment: Only difference is the table. And I include this in a groupplot.

Comment: Well, if my code doesn't show the problem and yours does then, guess what? The problem is in the code you haven't shared. To confirm this, compile the MWE I posted and make sure that it does not show the problem for you. Then we'll know the problem is not in the code in the question.

Comment: I am sorry, I am quite busy. I don't think there is anything wrong with the code, I have written the code above. My data has 30 different tables with thousands of points, I don't know what can I do to make problem more clear. I have already extracted relevant part of the code.

Comment: @cfr I have edited my question, please see it.

Comment: We still need a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?s=1|1.4333). If you are too busy to clarify your question, how do you expect the rest of us (whose time is presumably much less valuable than yours) to help? Since you have something which works, why not stick with that if you don't have time to figure it out enough to make the question clear?

Comment: The code you've posted ***will not compile***. That is what is wrong with it. And, when supplemented with some stuff to make it compile, it produces a dashed line. So (1) it is not an MWE (cannot be copy-paste-compiled to reproduce the problem) and (2) when it is turned into an MWE in an attempt to remedy tht problem, it compiles with the expected results. Think about it this way, if you were in our position, how would you go about figuring out what is wrong? If the answer is that you couldn't because you couldn't reproduce the problem, then you will know precisely why the question is unclear.

Comment: @cfr I think the problem is with tikz externalize. However, I couldn't reduce code to provide a MWE. But if I remove tikz externalize, the problem disappears.

Comment: See the manual for **pgfplots**. I think you should use its externalisation for plots, if applicable. I'm sure it needs to know....

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I get with your code when I add some data from the manual:

[image: dashed line]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot [smooth, red, dashed, line width = 1.5] table[x=dof,y=L2]  {% page 46 sample data from manual
      dof L2 Lmax maxlevel
      5 8.31160034e-02 1.80007647e-01 2
      17 2.54685628e-02 3.75580565e-02 3
      49 7.40715288e-03 1.49212716e-02 4
      129 2.10192154e-03 4.23330523e-03 5
      321 5.87352989e-04 1.30668515e-03 6
      769 1.62269942e-04 3.88658098e-04 7
      1793 4.44248889e-05 1.12651668e-04 8
      4097 1.20714122e-05 3.20339285e-05 9
      9217 3.26101452e-06 8.97617707e-06 10
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unless you can provide the code which produces a dashed line over the top of the continuous line so we can reproduce the problem, I'm not sure that it is possible to be of much further help. All I can really say is: that's not what happens here, so something must be wrong with your code somewhere.

Comment: I have a long code, I can give that, but I don´t think that is the problem. Because all I do is the following :

 \nextgroupplot[ymax = 80,xmin = -2, xmax=10,xticklabel pos = right]

\addplot+[smooth,red,dashed,line width = 1.5] table  
{00275/P_12<->P_32.csv} ;

This is one of the problematic plots.

Comment: We don't need (or want) your entire code. What you do is remove parts of the code until you have the minimum required to reproduce the problem. Then you post that example. It should be minimal and it should show the problem when copy-paste-compiled. Without that, people can hazard guesses and you may get lucky. But you may whistle in the dark for a long time.

Comment: @cfr, it is very difficult to help someone, who actually refuse  (with hiding data which shows what is the really problem) any help. When he doesn't sent his  finding in announced test of my suggestion in comment, I give up with further help (since I as others haven't crystal ball :-(  to see, if I correct guess what is the problem).  And thank you for your comments!

Comment: @Zarko Indeed. I suspect this question will end up needing to be closed as unclear. It seems pretty hopeless ;).

Comment: @cfr, I will vote to close this question. It is really unclear.

Comment: @Zarko I think it is a bit soon. It is not a very experienced user and it has only been 2 hours. What's the hurry?

Comment: @Zarko I have edited my question, please see it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}    
\begin{axis}
\addplot [red, only marks, mark=*, mark size=2pt] %, mark repeat={2}] 
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.6 2.64921945346413\\
0.7 2.44758628403132\\
0.8 2.24595311459851\\
0.9 2.04431994516571\\
1 1.8426867757329\\
1.1 1.64105360630009\\
1.2 1.43942043686729\\
1.3 1.23778726743448\\
1.4 1.03615409800167\\
1.5 0.834520928568865\\
1.6 0.632887759136058\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To display the markers only, you can use `\addplot[red,only marks] table {};` as pointed out by @Zarko in a comment. The marker can be chosen from a number of symbols (`*`, `-`, `+`, etc.) or you can define your own like this:

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{<name>}{<code that draws the marks>}
```

**EDIT:**

To make your markers less dense, you can add the option `mark repeat={<integer>}`. If this `integer` is 2, then you plot only every second mark, if this `integer` is 3, then you plot only every third mark, etc.

Here is the output now with `integer` equal to 2 (compare to the original one):

[image]

Comment: This was Zarko's answer and it is not very courteous to ignore that fact. If this is what the OP wants, it would be much better for the OP to ask Zarko to write the comment up as an answer. Please excuse me if I'm missed some way in which this differs from Zarko's suggestion.

Comment: No this is not I want, because I have a lot of points.

Comment: @Bronsteinx   What is it that you don't want? The markers? Their shape? No markers at all? Please clarify what you want. People here can help you only after they understand your question!!

Comment: Thanks for your effort. The problem is while you have 10 points, I have much more points so when I use your code it looks like a continuous line.

Comment: @Bronsteinx  Please see my edit.

Comment: @AboAmmar Thanks a lot. This wasn't what I wanted initially, but it is enough for my purposes. I don't want to mark your answer as correct answer immediately, because I want to know the solution to problem I described.